# No response data received from a jquery post to Google App Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, https, cross-domain

I am sending a post request to a Google App Script webapp from a webpage under different domain.
The doPost method at the GAS side handles the request, and returns a string.
I can see the request reaching the server, but no response is received at the client side.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunc() {
$.post("https://googlewebappURL", postdata).done(function(responsedata) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + responsedata);
});
};
</script>
```

The alert call does not happen.
The post does reach the web app, my logs confirm that.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your javascript works fine. For your situation, I think of the following confirmation points.

### Confirmation points :

- It seems that `postdata` is not defined.
- When the script was modified, whether the script version was updated and deployed Web Apps as the new version. How to deploy Web Apps is as follows.

  - On the Script Editor
  - Publish

    - Deploy as Web App

      - Create new Project version
      - At Execute the app as, select "your account"
      - At Who has access to the app, select "Anyone, even anonymous"
      - Click "Deploy"
      - Copy "Current web app URL"
      - Click "OK"

The detail of deploying Web Apps is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Even if you confirm above points, if the problem is not solved, can you try a simple sample as follows? If the modified your script didn't work, you can also use a curl sample. When the sample works, you retrieve `value`.

### Sample :

#### Google Apps Script : code.gs

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.key);
}
```

#### Modified your script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var postdata = {key: "value"}; // Added
$.post("https://googlewebappURL", postdata).done(function(responsedata) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + responsedata);
});
});
</script>
```

#### curl sample :

```
curl -L -d "key=value" "https://googlewebappURL"
```

If above samples didn't work, can I ask you about your `doPost()`? If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks!.. I was indeed missing something trivial.

Comment: @sg1 Welcome. Thank you, too.